# Merge multiple lists of dictionaries and rename the key

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the most pythonic way to merge two list dictionaries please? Say I have two list of dictionaries as:

```
sold=[
{'dept': '001', 'sku': 'foo', 'qty': 100},
{'dept': '002', 'sku': 'bar', 'qty': 200},
{'dept': '003', 'sku': 'baz', 'qty': 300}
]

returns=[
{'dept': '001', 'sku': 'foo', 'qty': 10},
{'dept': '002', 'sku': 'bar', 'qty': 20}
]

desired_output=[
{'dept': '001', 'sku': 'foo', 'sold': 100, 'return': 10},
{'dept': '002', 'sku': 'bar', 'sold': 200, 'return': 20},
{'dept': '003', 'sku': 'baz', 'sold': 300, 'return': 0}
]
```

The code below worked, but is there a more elegant/pythonic way to do this please

```
merge = []
for s in sold:
    found = False
    for r in returns:
        if (s.get('sku') == r.get('sku') and s.get('dept') == r.get('dept')):            
            merge.append({'sku': r.get('sku'), 'dept': r.get('dept'), 'sold': s.get('qty'), 'return': r.get('qty')})
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        merge.append({'sku': s.get('sku'), 'dept': s.get('dept'), 'sold': s.get('qty'), 'return': 0})
```

I have checked this post: [How to merge lists of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421906/how-to-merge-lists-of-dictionaries), it doesn't give me exactly what I want:

1. I need to merge by multiple keys, i.e. sku and dept
2. I have to rename the qty to sold and return respectively from 2 lists of dictionaries.

I tried something like below but couldn't get it work:

```
result = [
    s['return'] = r['qty'] 
    for s in sold 
    for r in return 
    if s['sku'] == r['sku'] and s['dept'] == r['dept']]
```

Thanks

Comment: I have a hard time believing that code worked.  `return` is a keyword, and so can't be used as a variable name..

Comment: sorry it's puedo code, I've just had it updated. ignore the vairable name please, the nested loop way does work, but it doesn't look very phythonic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mutates the `sold` dictionary.

```
temp = {(cd["dept"], cd["sku"]):cd["qty"] for cd in returned}

for cd in sold:
    cd["sold"] = cd["qty"]
    del cd["qty"]
    cd["return"] = temp.get((cd["dept"], cd["sku"]), 0)

print sold
```

If you don't want to mutate it, you can use this

```
temp, result = {(cd["dept"], cd["sku"]):cd["qty"] for cd in returned}, []

for cd in sold:
    temp_dict = {}
    for k, v in cd.items():
        if k == "sold":
            temp_dict["sold"] = cd["qty"]
        else:
            temp_dict[k] = cd[k]
    temp_dict["return"] = temp.get((cd["dept"], cd["sku"]), 0)
    result.append(temp_dict)

print result
```

**Output**

```
[{'sku': 'foo', 'dept': '001', 'sold': 100, 'return': 10},
 {'sku': 'baz', 'dept': '002', 'sold': 200, 'return': 20},
 {'sku': 'foo', 'dept': '003', 'sold': 300, 'return': 0}]
```

Comment: Thanks again thefourtheye, I like the 2nd approach. Just a minor thing, i guess you really meant: if k=="qty": temp_dict["sold"] = cd["qty"] ?