# Pythonic way to copy a key/value from one dict to another

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking for a concise way of taking two dicts that have a common key/value, and copying a key and value into one of the dicts.  Example:

```
d1 = [{'name': 'john', 'uid': 'ax01', 'phone': '555-555-5555'},
    {'name': 'jane', 'uid': 'ax02', 'phone': '555-555-5555'},
    {'name': 'jimmy', 'uid': 'ax03', 'phone': '555-555-5555'}]

d2 = [{'uid': 'ax01', 'orderid': '9999', 'note': 'testing this'},
      {'uid': 'ax02', 'orderid': '6666', 'note': 'testing this'},
      {'uid': 'ax03', 'orderid': '7777', 'note': 'testing this'}]
```

Here `uid` is the key that I want to use to then copy the `orderid` key and the value for that matching data point.  In the end I'd get something like:

```
output = [
    {'name': 'john', 'uid': 'ax01', 'phone': '555-555-5555', 'orderid': '9999'},
    {'name': 'jane', 'uid': 'ax02', 'phone': '555-555-5555', 'orderid': '6666'},
    {'name': 'jimmy', 'uid': 'ax03', 'phone': '555-555-5555', 'orderid': '7777'}
]
```

Where the `orderid` is pulled into `d1`.  I'm looking for the pythonic way if at all possible.

Comment: Are the list items always in corresponding order? Is `d1[i]["uid"] == d2[i]["uid"]` true for all `i`?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421906/how-to-merge-lists-of-dictionaries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dict()` to copy one dictionary and pass in the extra key. You need to create a mapping from `uid` to `orderid` first though:

```
uid_to_orderid = {d['uid']: d['orderid'] for d in d2}
output = [dict(d, orderid=uid_to_orderid[d['uid']]) for d in d1]
```

This assumes that you want to leave the dictionaries in `d1` untouched otherwise. Other assumptions made are that `uid` values are unique, and that all `uid` values in `d1` are present in `d2`.

Demo:

```
>>> d1 = [{'name': 'john', 'uid': 'ax01', 'phone': '555-555-5555'},
...     {'name': 'jane', 'uid': 'ax02', 'phone': '555-555-5555'},
...     {'name': 'jimmy', 'uid': 'ax03', 'phone': '555-555-5555'}]
>>> d2 = [{'uid': 'ax01', 'orderid': '9999', 'note': 'testing this'},
...       {'uid': 'ax02', 'orderid': '6666', 'note': 'testing this'},
...       {'uid': 'ax03', 'orderid': '7777', 'note': 'testing this'}]
>>> uid_to_orderid = {d['uid']: d['orderid'] for d in d2}
>>> [dict(d, orderid=uid_to_orderid[d['uid']]) for d in d1]
[{'orderid': '9999', 'phone': '555-555-5555', 'name': 'john', 'uid': 'ax01'}, {'orderid': '6666', 'phone': '555-555-5555', 'name': 'jane', 'uid': 'ax02'}, {'orderid': '7777', 'phone': '555-555-5555', 'name': 'jimmy', 'uid': 'ax03'}]
```

Comment: Do you maybe mean `dict2['orderid']`? What happens if they aren't ordered?

Comment: @C.B.: Ah, misunderstood.

Comment: Yeah, so in this case these are two separate data sources that I need to then create an output for.  The ordering can be totally anything.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer @Martijn Pieters

I can't think of a clever way to protect against missing data other something brutish like this:

```py
d1 = [{'name': 'john', 'uid': 'ax01', 'phone': '555-555-5555'},
    {'name': 'jane', 'uid': 'ax02', 'phone': '555-555-5555'},
    {'name': 'jimmy', 'uid': 'ax03', 'phone': '555-555-5555'},
    {'name': 'jack', 'uid': 'ax04', 'phone': '555-555-5555'},
    {'name': 'joan', 'uid': 'ax05', 'phone': '555-555-5555'}]
d2 = [{'uid': 'ax01', 'orderid': '9999', 'note': 'testing this'},
    {'uid': 'ax02', 'orderid': '6666', 'note': 'testing this'},
    {'uid': 'ax03', 'orderid': '6666', 'note': 'testing this'},
    {'uid': 'ax05', 'orderid-not-here': '7777', 'note': 'testing this'}]
    
def get_orderid(search):
    match = [x for x in d2 if x['uid']==search]
    if len(match) == 0:
        return 'None'
    else:
        return match[0].get('orderid','None')
        
    
results = [dict(d, orderid=get_orderid(d['uid'])) for d in d1]
print(results)
```

Output :

```bash
[{'name': 'john', 'orderid': '9999', 'phone': '555-555-5555', 'uid': 'ax01'},
{'name': 'jane', 'orderid': '6666', 'phone': '555-555-5555', 'uid': 'ax02'},
{'name': 'jimmy', 'orderid': '6666', 'phone': '555-555-5555', 'uid': 'ax03'},
{'name': 'jack', 'orderid': 'None', 'phone': '555-555-5555', 'uid': 'ax04'},
{'name': 'joan', 'orderid': 'None', 'phone': '555-555-5555', 'uid': 'ax05'}]
```